# Is there a good algorithm to reconstruct a global ranked list from several partially ranked lists?

Tags: python, list, ranking

I have a list of objects which are being reviewed by a team of judges. Each judge only sees a subset of the objects, and each judge ranks the objects from best to worst. Each object is ranked by at least two judges, and there is possibility of the judges to disagree (i.e., this is a noisy judging process). No judge sees all the objects.

Is there a good algorithm to compile the "best" global list of rankings given the collection of partial ranked lists from all the judges?

An example in Python (treat it as pseudocode):

```py
# Let's say there are six things and we want to rank them.

# There are ... four judges, each of whom judges three things, 
# so each thing gets judged twice.

items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
j1_rank = ['a', 'c', 'e']
j2_rank = ['b', 'd', 'f']
j3_rank = ['a', 'b', 'c']
j4_rank = ['d', 'e', 'f']
# these are ranked low to high

# the goal is - can we combine together ranks j1-j4 to reproduce a master ranked list
expected_ranked_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

I've taken a look at rank aggregation algorithms, but most of the online materials I've found are very technical and/or mathematical or in scientific literature with much jargon; many of these are more about ranked-choice voting (e.g. for political candidates), which is not a similar problem to what I'm facing.

Edit: As pointed out by @JoshGordon and @SurajShourie, I believe another acceptable expected solution would be `['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'f']`.

Comment: I think the straightforward approach is to rank the items by their mean position within each judge's list.  `a` appears twice at position 0, so its mean is 0.  `b` and `d` both appear once at 0 and once at 1, so they both have a mean of 0.5.  `c` appears once at 1 and once at 2, so its mean is 1.5.  And so on.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach places 'd' in the wrong place:  


```rankings = [j1_rank, j2_rank, j3_rank, j4_rank]  ;

for item in items:  ;
    ranks = []  ;
    for ranking in rankings:  ;
        if item in ranking:  ; 
            ranks.append(ranking.index(item))  ;
    average_rank = np.mean(ranks)  ;
    print(f"{item} has average rank {average_rank}")``` ;

a has average rank 0.0  ; 
b has average rank 0.5  ;
c has average rank 1.5  ;
d has average rank 0.5  ;
e has average rank 1.5  ;
f has average rank 2.0

Comment: To clarify the above comment: since 'd' always appears after 'b' wherever they both occur, I would expect it to rank after 'b' in the global ranking (which is not preserved in this proposed solution).

Comment: @JohnGordon I believe that the algorithm is agnostic to whether left is lowest or highest, as long as consistency is used throughout

Comment: I don't see how the expected rank can possibly be correct.  `b` and `d` have effectively identical rankings in the judge lists, each placing once at 0 and once at 1.  `c` cannot possibly be placed between those two.  Why is it that way in the expected rank?

Comment: Also @tomr_stargazer why would `c` come before `d` in your expected_output?

Comment: @SurajShourie @JohnGordon Great catch – since 'c' and 'd' are never directly compared and otherwise fall between 'b' and 'e', their relative rank would be ambiguous (so I would expect either `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']` or `['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'f']` as valid solutions)

Comment: This is just “voting”, for which there are [many common algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_method#Condorcet_ranking_methods) and [no best answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem).

Comment: Again, I don't see how that first solution is possible.  I don't see how `c` can be between `b` and `d`.  I would expect `c` to be to the right of both.

Comment: @DavisHerring I think the thing that separates this from a usual Condorcet voting scenario is that a given judge *only* sees the objects that they rank; they have no information (locally) on the unranked objects, whereas (I interpret) the Condorcet methods as ranking the voted-upon entrants above not-voted-upon entrants. (Maybe I’m wrong!)

Comment: @tomr_stargazer: That’s a good point, but some methods like [ranked pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranked_pairs) seem easy to generalize for that case, and others can be made to support it at worst by replicating the judges with random rankings for the censored objects.

Comment: @DavisHerring I appreciate that - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've come up with a (brute-force) solution to my toy example.  I believe I implicitly was looking for a [Kemeny-Young](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kemeny%E2%80%93Young_method) solver, i.e. one that minimized the number of pairwise disagreements between the set of partial rankings and the solved global ranking.

Here's my solution:

```py
j1_rank = ['a', 'c', 'e']
j2_rank = ['b', 'd', 'f']
j3_rank = ['a', 'b', 'c']
j4_rank = ['d', 'e', 'f']

# the goal is - can we combine together ranks j1-j4 
# to reproduce a master ranked list
expected_ranked_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

def Kemeny_metric(global_rank, partial_ranks):
   
   score = 0
   
   # for each pair in the global rank
   for i, gi in enumerate(global_rank):
       
       for j, gj in enumerate(global_rank[i+1:]):
           
           # check each pair in each partial rank
           for k, pr in enumerate(partial_ranks):
               
               try:
                   if pr.index(gi) > pr.index(gj):
                       #** Pair {gi}, {gj} are violated in partial ranking {k}
                       score += 1
                   else:
                       #   Pair {gi}, {gj} are well-ordered in partial ranking {k}
                       pass
               except ValueError:
                   #   Pair {gi}, {gj} are not both in partial ranking {k}
                   pass
   return score

from itertools import permutations

for i, perm in enumerate(permutations(expected_ranked_list)):

   score = Kemeny_metric(perm, [j1_rank, j2_rank, j3_rank, j4_rank])

   if score==0:

       print(i, perm, score)
```

This script yields:

```py
# >> 0 ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f') 0
# >> 6 ('a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'f') 0
```

which matches my intuition that `'b'` should always score above `'d'` but that `'c'` and `'d'` should have a tie.

My next task is to find an algorithm to solve (or approximately solve) this problem in the case for larger lists of items. I'm beginning my search here: [*Experiments with Kemeny ranking: What works when?*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0165489611000989)

I'll leave this up for a couple days for comment before I mark it as "answered". Thanks to everyone who left comments or answers!

Answer (score 0):

My previous response did not took into consideration position of the judge ranks, I'll leave it below as obsolete and bad solution. Here is a good one:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
j1_rank = ['a', 'c', 'e']
j2_rank = ['b', 'd', 'f']
j3_rank = ['a', 'b', 'c']
j4_rank = ['d', 'e', 'f']

j1_rank = dict(map(lambda x: (x, len(j1_rank) - j1_rank.index(x)), j1_rank))
// transforms list to the dictionary that has looks like:
// {'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'e': 1}
j2_rank = dict(map(lambda x: (x, len(j2_rank) - j2_rank.index(x)), j2_rank))
j3_rank = dict(map(lambda x: (x, len(j3_rank) - j3_rank.index(x)), j3_rank))
j4_rank = dict(map(lambda x: (x, len(j4_rank) - j4_rank.index(x)), j4_rank))
res = defaultdict(int)
for item in items:
    res[item] += j1_rank.get(item, 0)
    res[item] += j2_rank.get(item, 0)
    res[item] += j3_rank.get(item, 0)
    res[item] += j4_rank.get(item, 0)
// this will build dict with ranks accumulated:
// {'a': 6, 'b': 5, 'c': 3, 'd': 5, 'e': 3, 'f': 2}
res = dict(sorted(res.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
// and then sort it
print(list(res.keys()))  // and print keys in order
```

**OBSOLETE**

An excellent Python built-in function can help - [`collections.Count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). You can append all results to a single list, count it (into dict), and transform it back to the list.
Here is an example:

```py
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
j1_rank = ['a', 'c', 'e']
j2_rank = ['b', 'd', 'f']
j3_rank = ['a', 'b', 'c']
j4_rank = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'c']  // added 'c' so it will have a higher ranking

items.extend(j1_rank)  // appending to the original items, as there can be a
items.extend(j2_rank)  // situation where some element is not included 
items.extend(j3_rank)  // into rankings
items.extend(j4_rank)

a = dict(collections.Counter(items))  
// this will give something like {'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 3, 'e': 3, 'f': 3}
a = dict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
// sort it by value in reverse order {'c': 4, 'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'd': 3, 'e': 3, 'f': 3}

print(list(a.keys()))  // get keys and transform it to the list.
```

Comment: Doesn’t this completely ignore the order of each judge’s ranking?

Comment: @AleksandarVaricak I'm with Davis – I took a look at this method but when I remove the original contents of `items` (which should not be part of the input – it's a re-statement of the expected output) and replace it with an empty list `[]` at the beginning, I get a pretty garbled output which appears to simply reflect the order the items were originally added: `['a', 'c', 'e', 'b', 'd', 'f']`. (I also removed the extra `'c'` from `j4_rank` here.)

Comment: I've missed the order part, let me work on it and get back to you

Comment: Hey @AleksandarVaricak, thanks for the revised version. I think this solver does a good job solving a specific problem, but it's slightly different from the problem I've formulated. If you have thoughts after taking a look at my proposed answer, feel free to let me know!